# Require password when returning from sleep: Opensuse Leap 15, budgie-desktop

Tags: passwords, sleep, opensuse, xscreensaver

When I wake my laptop from a suspended state, there is no password prompt. I'd instead like to require a password to use the laptop.

I've looked in Settings > Power and Settings > Privacy but these aren't giving the the options to enable a password.

[image: power settings]

[image: privacy settings]

Comment: Normally screen locking is a screensaver function - as I can see nothing there for screensaver options, I'm guessing you need to run `xscreensaver-demo` seperately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally screen locking is a screensaver function - as I can see nothing there for screensaver options, I'm guessing you need to run xscreensaver-demo seperately...